# LMS component for Joomla 1.6

Tags: joomla

is there a LMS component for Joomla 1.6?

I could find components for Joomla 1.5. Is there a way to make them work in 1.5?

Comment: What exactly is LMS? Many 1.5-Extensions are currently migrated to 1.6 ... so just look on the homepages of the extensions if this is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your best bet may be to wait for the developers of one of the components that you found to update them to be compatible with 1.6.

However, if you feel so inclined, you could go through the process of updating these components yourself. [http://docs.joomla.org/Tutorial:Upgrade_Joomla_1.5_Extension_to_Joomla_1.6](http://docs.joomla.org/Tutorial%3aUpgrade_Joomla_1.5_Extension_to_Joomla_1.6) contains a list of items that would need to be updated and if you use Eclipse as an IDE, it also explains how to automate some of those update tasks.

Keep in mind, that changes that you make will likely be difficult to integrate with any future version of the component that are released by the developer.

Comment: If you do migrate a component, just send it to the developer of it so that he can pick up your work! Will help you both in the long run.